# How to render Sass/scss with Visual Studio Code on remote?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

I'm looking for a tool, an extension which compile/render scss and sass file to css on the server.

I know there is [Live Sass Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass). But it only compiles on the local. Sometimes I need to work on the remote/server. I'm using [ftp-simple extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humy2833.ftp-simple) to work on the remote files. But I can't compile scss files.

Is there any solution for that?

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic on SO.

Comment: I'm not asking extension, I'm asking for method

Comment: Maybe you should remove "I'm looking for a tool, an extension [...]" then

Answer (score -1):

if you are using node-sass then you just add **"compile:sass": "node-sass src/assets/sass/main.scss src/assets/css/style.css -w",** in your package.json file,
Like this.

For automatic compile/render use **-w**, it means vs code watching your sass code whenever you writing it.

```
"scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass src/assets/sass/main.scss src/assets/css/style.css -w",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
  },
```

or if you are doing in another way than you have check this link [sass compile in vs code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css).

Comment: this answer ignores the remote part